# Crontab doesn't execute .sh script in Amazon-EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, cron

I setted up a Cron Job in Amazon-EC2.
First, I edited the crontab:
`crontab -e`
Adding the following:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/run.sh &>> /home/ubuntu/output.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/uptime > /tmp/uptime
```

The content of `run.sh` is just

```
echo 123;
echo 321;
```

The `uptime` file is being updated with something like:

```
12:57:01 up  1:07,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
```

However, the `output.txt` file remains empty.
Executing `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` returns:

```
root         440       1  0 11:50 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

And executing `crontab -l` outputs the content I added through `crontab -e`
Running `run.sh` with `:~$ /home/ubuntu/run.sh &>> /home/ubuntu/output.txt` appends `output.txt` file as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to modify your `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/echo 123
/usr/bin/echo 321
```

Comment: Same result. =(